# Sequel + Sinatra + Phusion Passenger + MySQL Connection Management

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, sequel

We are using Sinatra and Sequel for a small API implementation. The problem we have however is that on every page request Sequel opens new connections to MySQL, and keeps them open till they timeout, or you restart Apache.

There's not a lot of documentation on how to reuse connections, so any help, explanations, and/or pointers in the right direction would help.

Comment: Where do you set up your connection? could you post some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out what we were doing wrong. It was rather stupid, we initialized Sequel in a before filter in Sinatra.

So instead we do:

```
DB = Sequel.mysql("...")
```

Then we simply use the `DB` constant to use Sequel.

Comment: Where is this placed?  Mine (just recent) is in the __before__ block.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped the Sequel stuff in a tiny wrapper and reuse this wrapper, like this:

```
get '/api/:call' do
  @@api ||= SApi.new
  @@api.call(params[:call])
end

class SApi
  def initialize
    connect
  end
  def connect
    @con = Sequel.connect("...")
  end
  def call(x)
    #handle call using @con
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can call @con.disconnect once you're finished or call Sequel.connect using a block:

```
Sequel.connect("...") do |c|
   # work with c
end #connection closed
```

Comment: Thanks, however we've already resolved this the problem in a different manner. I just forgot to close/answer the question *whistles* :)

Comment: Care to share the answer?  I'm in here with a similar `PostgreSQL` application.

Comment: @Rich_F: the solution by jimeh is given above as a regular (accepted) answer.

Comment: @bb Not sure what it means.  So __not__ use a DB constant in the __before__ block?  that's what I'm doing now.  I'm assuming it's synchronous and closes at the end of the `route`.

Comment: @Rich_F: jimeh might want to explain his answer himself (but be aware it's more than ten years old). I think what he did was not calling Sequel.mysql() per request but once and store that connection as a constant and use the constant in the requests.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and I'm wondering if that dataset has been copied as an intermediate.  @jimeh?

Comment: It was over ten years ago, so I don't even recall what this API was for anymore. But from what I can gather and vaguely recall, the code was originally initializing a new database connection on each request, rather than create and reuse a single database connection object before any request handling comes into play.